# Should these kind of questions go to Programmers?

Tags: discussion, migration, site-recommendation

I stumbled upon a [particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049955/page-flow-diagram-for-ajax-web-2-0-design) on Stack Overflow that is not programming related, but it is development related. More architect work though.

Where should these kind of questions be migrated to have at least some chance of getting answered?

Comment: The question you linked is not a very good one.  It's not at all clear what the OP wants.  Consequently, it's difficult to evaluate on which site it belongs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I agree and I'm also aware that these kind of conceptual soft-logic things always tend to be more vague than the clearly definable programming related topics...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking questions that are about anything in the [SDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life-cycle) other than implementation are on topic on Programmers. That includes software architecture, analysis & design, testing, etc, check out our [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details.

However the question you linked to isn't really suitable for us, I've read it twice and I'm not sure what the OP wants, or why their current diagram is insufficient (well I can see why it's insufficient, it's a mess, but that's my problem with it not theirs). I've posted a comment to the question pointing them to sequence diagrams, but that's more of a guess really.

Comment: Honestly, I've never really understood what should go to programmers.se. I've several times flagged offtopic questions on SO which seem to be a better fit for programmers.se (indeed mainly architecture, analysis, design and testing), but no one of them was ever migrated, it was either closed or declined/ignored. For example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917323/what-is-the-point-of-unit-testing Why would this one not be migrated to programmers.se?

Comment: @Chichiray Hm, I think that's borderline not constructive, it's more of an opinion piece than an actual question, imho. But, yes, a less rant-y version of would fit perfectly on Programmers. I don't know why your flags were declined / ignored, what I can tell you is that as a rule of thumb we don't migrate sub par questions, so you might be right that the questions you found were more appropriate for Programmers than SO in terms of topicality, but weren't right in terms of quality.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I share your sentiment regarding the chaotic diagram that's also rather unusable to me. It is usually better to provide several diagrams from conceptual level drilling down to individual feature details (if they need detailed explanation).

Comment: @Chichiray to stay on a safe side at Programmers, test whether question wording allows to [repel low-effort answers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3835/31260 "more details here"). Example test for the [question you referred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917323) would be like: if there is an answer "unit test once helped me avoid a regression", could you come to Programmers Meta, say _"Here's the question, here's the answer, I don't feel like the answer is OK"_ and have a good chance of garbage being downvoted by active community members who happen to read your post?